# i cannot get glassfish to render my jsp code

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, glassfish

I have glassfish v3

I have the following code

```
<%@page import="java.io.*;" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*;" %>

<%

Connection con=null;
ResultSet rst=null;
Statement stmt=null;

try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/achme_health";
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");

    stmt=con.createStatement();
    rst=stmt.executeQuery("select patient_no,fname,lname from patients");

    while(rst.next()){
         out.print(rst.getString(0));
         out.print(rst.getString(1));
         out.print(rst.getString(2));
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("-1");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line will throw a `SQLException` with a message like "invalid column index" (the exact message depends on the JDBC driver).

```
out.print(rst.getString(0));
```

The index namely starts at 1, not 0. Fix your code accordingly.

```
out.print(rst.getString(1));
out.print(rst.getString(2));
out.print(rst.getString(3));
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please note that you're only printing the exception message to the logs (did you read it?) instead of throwing the whole exception and/or dumping the entire stacktrace. This is unhelpful in debugging. I'd suggest to revise your poor exception handling approach. Also that Java code is preferably to placed in a real Java class rather than a JSP file.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: ive adjusted my code to the following: still nothing shows <%


System.out.println("show me something");


%>

Comment: Did you fix the incorrect `getString()` index? This line prints to system log, not to the browser screen. What happens instead? What do you retrieve in browser? Rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*, what do you see?

Comment: How does the generated HTML page look?